# BigQuery export/copy internal Error

Tags: google-bigquery

I try to copy/export table today, and hit the BigQuery error like following:

{"errorResult":{"message":"Unexpected. Please try again.","reason":"internalError"},
 "errors":[{"message":"Unexpected. Please try again.","reason":"internalError"}],
 "state":"DONE"}

But only the table created today. The old table export / copy works fine.

Is BigQuery having some problem today?

Is there anyone hit the same problem?

Comment: Can you share job IDs for the failures?  This helps BigQuery engineers to look up internal failure details for your jobs.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809810/unexpected-please-try-again-error-when-copying-bigquery-table.

Comment: @DannyKitt I just do copy again, and still fail. The job ID is studio-bdi-prod:job_M1KSzS674UC6CXcupdLRrGLU1FY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All affected tables were cleaned up and should now copy/export successfully -- sorry!  (Mentioned on ["Unexpected. Please try again" error when copying BigQuery table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809810), but just to have it visible over here.)