# "Unexpected. Please try again" error when copying BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to copy an existing table, and the job fails with error "Unexpected. Please try again" with no other information.  I get the same result whether doing it in the web console or through the bq command line tool.  Here is the the job id: arcx-prod:job_XVgg_YqvXZRTFucTJhhh8D-cWU8.

A few potentially related pieces of information:

1. copying succeeds for other tables in the same project
2. exporting data from this table also fails with the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in the latest BigQuery release. The problematic release has been rolled back, and we are in the process of fixing the metadata for all affected tables. Apologies for the errors!

Edit: All tables fixed as of November 19, 2014.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Any idea when the metadata will be fixed for my projects?

Comment: Soon! Hopefully today or tomorrow. Resolving the issue is at the top of our list.

Comment: Please kindly notify me when it's resolved.  We have a critical production dependency on this.  Thanks!

Comment: Will do. Apologies for the issue! We're working to clean it up right now.

Comment: We've run a one-off cleanup against the table referenced by your job, which hopefully unblocks you. If you still see problems, or if there are other tables that we should prioritize, send me email at jcondit@google.com. Thanks, and sorry again for the trouble!

Comment: Appreciate the extra effort!  Confirmed that this table is fixed and working.  However, there are other tables in the same project that we need copying to work.  Do you mind running this one-off process on all the tables in that project?  Thanks much!

Comment: I am getting this same error with a table I created today. The job ID is persuasive-axe-847:job_1LxXFWUOWordhESJXt6Gu15Ffe0 I have tried re-creating the table (using the same schema) and the copy fails every time. Does this have anything to do with the schema I am using? Are there any restrictions I should be aware of?

Comment: Christina, that's an unrelated issue, but I've filed a bug internally so that we can investigate. In the future, I'd suggest reporting bugs at our external issue tracker to ensure that they get appropriate attention: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues

Answer (score 1):

All tables should be working (as of late Nov 14); please let me know if you have any trouble.

<sub>*[I'd put this as a comment under Jeremy's answer but I don't have the karma yet to comment -- if anyone can edit it into a comment that would be great.]*</sub>